# How to output a twitter api respose using node js version 0.6.18

Tags: node.js, twitter

I wish to create a first node js app. For this I need to pull the public twitter tweet and output tweet as a request response. I searched a lot but I got code that written in older node version code(ie createServer, addListener something like this). How we write code for request a twitter call and output the json as response in node version 0.6.18?

Following is the older code I tried

```
var http = require("http");
var events = require("events");
var port = 8001;
var twitterClient = http.createClient(80, 'api.twitter.com');
var tweetEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var request = twitterClient.request("GET", "/1/statuses/public_timeline.json", {"host": "api.twitter.com"});

function getTweats() {

    request.addListener("response", function (response) {
        var body = "";

        response.addListener("data", function (data) {
            body += data;
        });

        response.addListener("end", function (end) {
            var tweets = JSON.parse(body);
            if (tweets.length > 0) {
                tweetEmitter.emit("tweets", tweets);
                console.log(tweets, 'tweets loaded');
            }
        });
    });

    request.end();
}

setInterval(getTweats(), 1000);


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log(uri);
    if (uri === '/stream') {
        var cb = function (tweets) {
            console.log('tweet'); // never happens!
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write(JSON.stringify(tweets));
            response.end();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
        tweetEmitter.addListener("tweets", cb);

        // timeout to kill requests that take longer than 10 secs
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write(JSON.stringify([]));
            response.end();
            tweetEmitter.removeListener("tweets", cb);
        }, 10000);

    } else {
        loadStaticFile(uri, response);
    }

}).listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:" + port + "/");
```

And got error

```
$ node tweet.js 
Server running at http://localhost:8001/

timers.js:223
    callback.apply(timer, args);
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:223:14)
```

Comment: **What have you tried?** - You implied you found some relevant code, but it didn't work.  Can you provide that?  And say what failed?

Comment: I added older code I tried please verify thanks

Comment: Just modified the timer as setInterval(getTweats(), 5000); and the first set of tweets are output to console. After that I get the same error you mentioned. So it seems basically a timing/ callback issue rather than anything with the code fetching the tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a common one. Instead of:

```
setInterval(getTweats(), 1000);
```

you need

```
setInterval(getTweats, 1000);
```

This is because you want `setInterval` to call the `getTweats` function *itself*.

Your code has `getTweats()` with parentheses instead. This *calls* `getTweats` first, and gives the *result* to `setInterval`. Since this result is `undefined` (your function doesn't return anything), node cannot call it.